# How to check if class has attribute that are other classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following Python code:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class customer_s3_buckets_object(BaseModel):
    class s3_bucket(BaseModel):
        access_key: str = None
        secret_key: str = None
        region: str = None
        name: str = None
    encryption_bucket: s3_bucket = s3_bucket()
    file_transfer_bucket: s3_bucket = s3_bucket()
    holding_bucket: s3_bucket = s3_bucket()

class customer_object(BaseModel):
    s3_buckets: customer_s3_buckets_object = customer_s3_buckets_object()
```

Assume further I have a variable `my_customer` that is of type `customer_object`. Customers may have any combination of the 3 s3 buckets. For example, some customers may only have a `holding_bucket` but no `file_transfer_bucket` and `encryption_bucket`.

When the customer does not have a bucket, then that attribute is set to `None` by another function that initializes `my_customer`.

So for example, an instance of `my_customer` could have:

- `my_customer.s3_buckets.encryption_bucket` set to a valid value
- `my_customer.s3_buckets.file_transfer_bucket` set to None
- `my_customer.s3_buckets.holding_bucket` set to None

Is there a way I can do the following test without the code crashing (and not using a `try / except` block)?

```
if s3_buckets.file_transfer_bucket.access_key in my_customer
  print("Yes, customer has file transfer bucket access key")
```

I'm just looking for a convenient way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to test for the case where `s3_buckets.file_transfer_bucket` is `None` before accesing its `access_key` attribute:

```
if s3_buckets.file_transfer_bucket is None:
   print('No file transfer bucket')
elif s3_buckets.file_transfer_bucket.access_key in my_customer:
    # file_transfer_bucket is guaranteed to not be None
    print("Yes, customer has file transfer bucket access key")
```

You may think this is tedious, and would prefer if both of these operations happened "automagically" in a single line. But the test needs to be done. Otherwise you won't be able to differentiate between the `if` clause failing because `file_transfer_bucket` is `None`, or because its `access_key` is not in `my_customer`.

You can "hide" this behavior somewhat by implementing a `get_access_key()` method, using properties, etc. But at some point the test needs to be done because `None` is a valid value for the `file_transfer_bucket` - even if it is done internally in one of your classes.

Perhaps a better alternative would be for clients to always have a `s3_bucket` instance as the `file_transfer_bucket` attribute, and setting its `access_key` to `None` when that bucket is "invalid" - but only you knows that for sure, since we don't know what your code is trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I had a chance to think through this further and I think I will take your approach or use a try / except block simply because both are 100% guarantees that my attribute is checked properly. Anything else out of convenience would seem "risky". I just thought there would be some kind of hasattr function I could use as a shortcut.

Comment: In the end, I believe a try / except block is easier to read in the code because I can put all the code I need to extract values from the various attributes into that block. If any single line fails, the exception will be caught.

Comment: @jsy I avoided using a try/except in my answer because you said you didn't want it, but I do agree that it is the best solution overall.